# ACID table error in IMPALA?Hive upgraded to Hive3

Tags: hive, bigdata, cloudera, impala

I am very new to Hive and Impala.

I was trying to run an already existing table in IMPALA but I got the following error.

`AnalysisException: Table dev_test.customer not supported. Transactional (ACID) tables are only supported when they are configured as insert_only.`

The version is Hive 3. I am clueless as in what to do. I did see some documentation, articles online, but still could not solve the issue. I have attached a screenshot of the error screen.  Let me know if you need more information.

[image]

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you cant see the data through Impala and you have to use hive.
you can change table properties to insert_only to see this data.

```
alter TABLE tmp2 set
TBLPROPERTIES ( 
  'transactional'='true', 'transactional_properties'='insert_only'
  );
```

[image: Screenshot of statement output]
When you set  a table to FULL ACID or hive upgrades to full acid, table file format changed to `ORC` and this is not supported by Impala so you can not access them.  So you need to use hive to access these tables.
If you choose the workaround and change table properties, you will loose all ACID benefits like UPD/DEL etc.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Koushik. Can you please let me know where to change the table properties?

Comment: you can use `alter table set`. I have tested the statements on my env - it works(screenshot attached).

Comment: Sadly, @Koushik Its not working for me. And I am getting the same error(Screenshot attached).

Comment: You are running it from Impala. Switch your tool to hive in hue and try to alter it. You can access from impala only after successful altercation.

Comment: I realized it. I did run it in Hive. I got his error saying `Error while compiling statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 40013 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.ddl.DDLTask. Unable to alter table. TBLPROPERTIES with 'transactional_properties' cannot be altered after the table is created`

Comment: hmm, then i would suggest create a new table with new properties. And then copy data from old table into this new table. sorry dont have much options here.